# SharePoint 2010 How do you work out what type of site a site it?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do you work out what type of site a site is in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: Needs more explanation. What "type" are you talking about?

Comment: You can create  a newt site you can create a team site, blank site etc. How do you know what template was used to create a site?

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, click the checkmark to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the object model, SPWeb.WebTemplate will tell you what template was used to the create the site.

Answer (score 7):

The by far easiest way to do this is to use PowerShell:

```
PS> asnp Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
PS> $web = get-spweb http://server/site
PS> $web.WebTemplate
YOURSITEDEF
PS> $web.WebTemplateId
12345
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to find out the template without writing code, there is a great tool called SharePoint Explorer that you can browse to find the web template and more.

http://spm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I found [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/10478/4718) from sharepoint.stackexchange.com useful: "View the HTML source of the page and search for 'g_wsaSiteTemplateId' - this will give you the site template and configuration used to create the site."

In my case the template is a Team Site:

```
var g_presenceEnabled = true;
var g_wsaEnabled = false;
var g_wsaLCID = 1033;
var g_wsaSiteTemplateId = 'STS#0';
var g_wsaListTemplateId = 119;
```

The other answers need to be performed on the server (or using remoting for the PowerShell option). That isn't always practical and this option can performed from any machine with web access to the site.